# How do I run multiple browsers to simulate multiple simultaneous users with Gauge?

Tags: javascript, testing, gauge, getgauge

I'm working on a web-based multiplayer game. It's the usual "One person creates a game, others join" type flow.  So I bring up multiple browsers to manually test the interaction.

Is there a way to do this with Gauge/Taiko?  The alternative seems to be setting up an existing scenario in the database, which seems like a lot more work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use https://docs.taiko.dev/#openincognitowindow to simultaneously login different users as this opens a new incognito profile for each window. Testing can be done by switching between the windows using the name given when opening the window.

Comment: That works, however 'switchTo' doesn't seem to be able to switch based on the window name you give 'openIncognitoWindow'.  It will switch based on window title, so I set that, and it works fine.

Comment: Do raise an issue here https://github.com/getgauge/taiko/issues, if you feel something is working differently